# What is the proper design pattern for a callback in destructor which uses a pointer which may or may not point to valid object?

Tags: c++

Let's say we have the following scenario.

We have a `ImageManager` class which is used to internally store and manage image data.
The `ImageManager` class has a public member `populateImage`, which will read an image into memory, then return a populated `MyImage` which is a `std::shared_ptr` around an `Image` object. This object will contain a `uuid` which maps to the image data which is managed by `ImageManager`.

Finally, we define a callback function which gets called in the `Image` destructor and properly cleans up the image data stored by the `ImageManager`.

Here is the example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

class Image {
public:
    Image() = default;
    ~Image(){
        if (m_deleter) {
            m_deleter();
        }
    }
private:
    friend class ImageManager;
    std::function<void()> m_deleter = nullptr;
    unsigned int m_uuid;
};

using MyImage = std::shared_ptr<Image>;

class ImageManager {
public:
    void removeImage(unsigned int uuid) {
        auto iter = m_imageMap.find(uuid);
        if (iter == m_imageMap.end()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to find image for UUID: " + std::to_string(uuid));
        }
        m_imageMap.erase(iter);
    }

    void populateImage(MyImage& image) {
        image = std::make_shared<Image>();

        static unsigned int uuid = 0;
        ++uuid;

        image->m_uuid = uuid;

        auto img = std::vector<uint8_t>(1000, 0);
        m_imageMap[uuid] = img;

        unsigned int currentUUID = uuid;
        auto callbackFunc = [this, currentUUID]() {
            this->removeImage(currentUUID);
        };

        image->m_deleter = callbackFunc;
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<uint8_t>> m_imageMap;
};
```

The issues arise when our instance of the `ImageManager` falls out of scope before our instances of `Image`, for example in the following driver code:

```
int main() {
    MyImage img1, img2;
    {
        ImageManager manager;
        manager.populateImage(img1);
        manager.populateImage(img2);
    }
}
```

Running this program prints:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Unable to find image for UUID: 2
```

But ultimately I understand that this is undefined behavior as the `this` pointer in `m_deleter` no longer points to a valid object.

What is the proper design pattern in order to avoid this problem?

Comment: Don't capture something in a lambda where the lambda will outlive the thing being captured.

Comment: Even if the `ImageManager` lifetime issue were fixed, another problem is `removeImage()` is throwing an exception inside the context of `Image`'s destructor. A destructor should NEVER throw an exception. There is no good reason for `removeImage()` to throw just because the requested `uuid` is not found. The image is no longer in the list, so the remove did its job.

Comment: @RemyLebeau good point.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. You'd be more likely to get answers.

Comment: When you return a shared pointer to the image, why is `Image img1` at all necessary? Can't this be handled internally and all you expose outside the class is the shared pointer?

Comment: @eerorika I'm not sure what you mean? The above code is a complete example and can be compiled, and demonstrates the problem I am I trying to solve.

Comment: @cyrusbehr But is it **minimal**? Is this a question about opencv? And no, this example cannot be compiled without opencv headers.

Comment: My bad, good point @eerorika, will modify the question to use a vector instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall the design smells. If the `ImageManager` is a local object, and `MyImage` are outside of the scope, why do you need to delete the items in the map?

Anyway, I promised you to show the shared/weak idiom. Wrap the map into a `shared_ptr`. That would mean that the map will be destroyed together with the ImageManager (if you wouldn't copy this shared pointer):

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<unsigned int, cv::Mat>> m_imageMap;
```

Store a weak pointer in the lambda:

```cpp
    std::weak_ptr<std::unordered_map<unsigned int, cv::Mat>> weakPtr = m_imageMap;
    auto callbackFunc = [weakPtr, uuid]() {
        auto imageMap = weakPtr.lock();
        if (imageMap)
            auto iter = imageMap.find(uuid);
            if (iter == imageMap.end()) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Unable to find image for UUID: " + std::to_string(uuid));
            }
            imageMap.erase(iter);
        }
    };
    image->m_deleter = callbackFunc;
```

Weak pointer will know whether the shared pointer counterpart is destroyed or not.

Keep in mind that you shouldn't use `std::make_shared` in this case: otherwise the memory associated with the map will be freed only when the last image is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the callback depends on the manager, it should have  ownership.

It cannot have proper ownership because the manager already owns the (object that contains) the callback, but it can have weak shared ownership. A working adjustment of your example:

```
class ImageManager : std::enable_shared_from_this<ImageManager> {
// ...

    auto callbackFunc = [this_w = weak_from_this(), currentUUID]() {
        if (auto this_ = this_w.lock())
            this_->removeImage(currentUUID);
    };
// ...

    auto manager = std::make_shared<ImageManager>();
    manager->populateImage(img1);
    manager->populateImage(img2);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this would be to remove the callbacks when the `ImageManager` is destroyed.
In the `ImageManager` destructor you can loop through `m_imageMap` and set all deleters to null.